# Jquery remove tag from HTML string

Tags: jquery, html

like

```
<table id="tableID">
-----     
<span id="someID"> ABCD...Z </span>
----
----
</table>
```

The result should be

```
<table id="tableID">
-----     
ABCD...Z
----
----
</table>
```

how can I achieve this by jquery ?

any help???

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the element using **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**:

```
$('span#someID').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```
$("#someID").replaceWith($("#someID").text());
```